# Microsoft Access VBA: Cannot find project or library

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem as below:

Title: MS Access 2000, Win 10 enterprise- Cannot find project or library.

Steps:

- I open a form,
- Click on a button (Click event).

Actual result:
- Cannot find project or library.

Notes: It works correctly on WinXP
Acction:
     I open Reference dialog box:
   [image]

But i dont know how to register the libs: JMAIL 4.0, MS Rich textbox control 6, MS Access Barcode control 9.

Please feel free to help me,

Let me know if there is any unclear in the post.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you [searched for your issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vbeditor+add+missing+references)?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Access 64bit Version? That could be the reason.

Comment: Office Libs V 9.0 fit to Access 2000. The refs are linked top to bottom? then `JMAIL 4.0`is missing.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that you are trying to open an Access file that was developed using certain Add-ons or applications, on a computer where these add-ons or applications are not installed.

Comment: I found the project problem already, Thank you very much. (Missing a hardcode folder).